# File as command line argument to spark action in Oozie workflow

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

How to pass a file as command line argument to spark job in Oozie workflow? My spark job is expecting a file as command line argument, but when I am pass that file in the workflow as /file/location it is not picking up that file.

Comment: Spark uses Hadoop libraries & configuration passed by Oozie, hence the default filesystem for Spark will be HDFS, hence `/file/location` means implicitly `hdfs:///file/location`. Is that what you expect?

Comment: I tried with that. It didn't work out.

Comment: And there is nothing in the **logs** that may explain what Spark tries, and whether it succeeds or fails or just does nothing?

Comment: Did you try? Yeah, I expect the same. But it didn't work even with hdfs uri.

Comment: It points to hdfs:/location/file instead of hdfs://location/file. I also consider / as escape sequence and tried with a combination. Nothing works, it points to only hdfs:/ with every combination.

Comment: And if the Spark code itself adds the `hdfs://` scheme explicitly if the argument has no scheme?

Comment: Did you try **three** slashes `:///` to mean "default filesystem,**absolute path**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one workaround, if we put the file in a custom-directory in ozzie shared library with a few additional change in job.properties

> - oozie.use.system.libpath=true
> - oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark,custom-directory
> - oozie.libpath=true

Then we need to update the shared lib using below command:

> `oozie admin -auth SIMPLE -sharelibupdate`

After that we can directly pick up the file by just using the name of the file, which we placed in custom-directory, in the oozie workflow.